# How To Create a Read or Format For an type Option[A]

Tags: scala

I have this case class:

```scala
final case class Email(value: String) extends AnyVal

object Email {

  implicit val format: Format[Email] =
    implicitly[Format[String]].inmap(Email(_), _.value)

}
```

I have this other type which has this definition:

```scala
sealed trait AccountType extends Product with Serializable

object Foo {

  final case class Personal(
    id: String
    email: Option[Email]
  ) extends AccountType

  final case class Organisation(
    id : String,
    name: Option[Name]
  ) extends AccountType


  implicit val format: OFormat[AccountType] = derived.oformat[AccountType]()

}
```

I use this: `https://github.com/julienrf/play-json-derived-codecs` for the sealed trait type.

But when I compile this I get:

```scala
No Json deserializer found for type Option[Email]. Try to implement an implicit Reads or Format for this type.
[error] Error occurred in an application involving default arguments.
[error]   implicit val format: OFormat[AccountType] = derived.oformat[AccountType]()
```

I am not sure how to implement a Reads or Format for Option[Email]

Comment: It's already implemented for Option[T] in `play.api.libs.json.Writes` and `play.api.libs.json.Reads` check if you import implicits properly.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Can you create a [MCVE]?

Comment: I found the problem: it's that Name type. I get that from some other library and it has just defined: object Name {
  val reads = Json.reads[Name]
}

Comment: So I guess it is complaining it wants a write for this as well. Because when I take this field out it all compiles which is super weird as it was complaining about Email.